# Getting a 405 error when i try to download a Crystal Report file from Android Studio WebView

Tags: android, crystal-reports

Im trying to download a crystal reports Report from inside an app WebView from android studio and it gives me the error 405. When I click on the download link it redirects me to internet and then it just gives me the error. Its not a error with permissions from Android Studio. I have also tried to download pre charged files from internet and it works well.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String url = "MYURL";

    private WebView mywebView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewCoto);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        mywebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        mywebView.loadUrl(url);
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


}
```

I want to get the download to work,but i dont know if it is an error with the code, or with the server in trying to use, becouse from internet with no webview or anything, just web, it works normally.